is there a way to get ONLY dev dependencies with `npm i` in 2024
I'm looking to get ONLY dev dependencies with npm i in 2024.
The following top answers on stackoverflow no long work
npm i --production=false
npm i --omit=prod
npm i --only=dev
npm i -D
Every one of these has been removed. I just thoroughly went through and the only way I was able to get JUST my dev dependencies was to actually delete everything within the dependencies obj and also delete my package-lock
I'm on npm v10.0.0 and node v20.6.0
{
  ...
  "dependencies:{},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.2.1",
    "mocha": "10.3.0"
  }
}

So this package.json comes in at 167 packages
But if you add anything inside dependencies it will cause that number to increase. In other words, dev only isn't really dev only.
Is there a way, in 2024, to actually get dev only dependencies and without having to duplicate the package.json or delete what's in the dependencies obj?
